# Errors not displaying when rendering edit in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, form-with

My app is running Rails Rails 7.0.2.3

In my update controller action I have the line:

```
return render(:edit) unless @user_form.save
```

This renders the edit view on error .... but errors are not displayed.

In my edit view I am defining the form with:

```
form_for @user_form, url: user_path(@user_form), method: :patch do |f|
```

The form submits via turbo. I can see the error being added to `@user_form.errors` in the controller, but the instance of `@user_form` in the view is not changing on each form submission. If I output `@user_form.inspect` to the view - the id remains the same on each submission.

I have tried adding `remote: false` to the `form_for` call, but this does not seem to have an effect.

The only solution I have found is to add `data: { turbo: false }` to the `form_for` call.

Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Turbolinks causes all sorts of problems and I long ago stripped it out of my Rails apps. (Which isn't very helpful to you, I know!) The problem sounds like a typical Turbolinks caching issue - it tries to minimise changes to the page to speed page renders, but it does make mistakes when detecting what needs to change. One option might be to create a new instance variable in the controller called `@errors` or similar, and to reference the errors there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render with `status: :unprocessable_entity`. I think the change in status invalidates the cache.

so change your code to:

```rb
return render(:edit, status: :unprocessable_entity) unless @user_form.save
```

Comment: Yes - I'm sure this is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use a partial to show the errors.

you'll need to add an `update.turbo_stream.erb` file to this view's directory. In that file have something like:

```rb
<%= turbo_stream.update 'id_of_div_where_you_want_to_show_errors' do %>
   <%= render partial: 'partial_that_displays_errors' %>
<% end %>
```

or your controllers update action you'll want to have something like

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream { turbo_stream.update 'id_of_div_where_you_want_to_show_errors', render partial: 'partial_that_displays_errors' %>
end
```

Treat all this more like pseudocode and apply it to your own app, it's hard to say what's going on without seeing your code.